# iMac 5K Bootcamp Black Screen when playing

Tags: bootcamp, imac, windows

I have an iMac 5k late-2014 with R9 M295x GPU, I'm using the graphic drivers from bootcampdrivers.com, as the default ones don't work with newer games like Forza Horizon 3... However, whenever the game is using much power, the iMac screen goes black, the fan speeds all the way up and after about 10-15 seconds it stops and the windows Login screen appears (no complete shutdown, only sleep mode), Applications and Games are still open but the network connection was gone (disconnected from online matches)... I had a freeze problem with macOS before but a complete formation of the Fusion Drive fixed this... If it isn't caused by the drivers, what could this be? GPU overheating, CPU or RAM not working correctly? GPU reaches about 110° max while playing. Thanks for your help!

Comment: According to http://safetemp.blogspot.co.uk/2016/01/radeon-r9-m295x-max-temp.html the TMax for that card is 105°C so I'd investigate airflow, if the fan can't keep up. When was the last time it was stripped & cleaned?

Answer (score 1):

By the sounds of it your iMac is overhheating.

A temperature of 110° is too much so your graphics card stops processing for some time in order to prevent any lasting damage to it. As it is only your GPU restarting and throttling, your applications are still open.

As the iMac is an all-in-one, some airflow and heat capacity drawbacks have to be taken.

In order to prevent this from happening you could do the following:

- decrease the graphics settings
- open your iMac and clean the air intakes and outlets to improve ariflow

But remember. The iMac was not designed for gaming on windows, so your experience will never be perfect. Drivers that have been tinkered with might work but should not be considered reliable.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I'll take a look at it and try to clean it.

Answer (score 1):

Your gpu is overheating you need to use macsfancontrol to increase the fans sooner and it should stop this from happening.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different!  We're trying to find the best answers and those answers will provide info as to why they're the best.  Answers should be self-contained so explain why you think the answer you provided will solve the problem or is better than others out there.  Providing links as supporting information can also help the OP, and others, find additional info for themselves.  See [answer] on how to provide a quality answer.